# lost dll - Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll

Tags: c#, dll, sdk, kinect

Hy!

Where can I find the  Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll? I have already installed the Kinect SDK 1.5 and the toolkit for this, but I do not find the dll. I have no idea. Pls if u know share it with me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please google your question next time.
I googled the dlls name and came up with [this article](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/faq-where-can-i-find-microsoft-research-kinect-dll/).

> Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll was the DLL name for our early beta
>   releases (beta 1, beta 1 refresh and beta 2) from 2011.
>
> In our final version 1.0 release (Feb 1, 2012), we changed the DLL
>   name to Microsoft.Kinect.dll and did a major refactoring of the API
>   surface of the Kinect for Windows SDK.

So it was renamed, the tutorial/article you are following is using old code so you need to migrate some of that code, for migrating tips see [this article](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-details-of-api-changes-from-beta2-to-v1-managed/)

In short:

**Dll's:**

`Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll` to `Microsoft.Kinect.dll`

**Namespaces:**

`Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui` **and** `Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Audio` to `Microsoft.Kinect`

Comment: It is ok. But I have a old project and It wants the Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll. And I does not like the "new one".

Comment: I have read the article you shared, but I am confused how do I change my code so that it runs on kinect SDK 1.8? Where do I need to rename these files?

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use de old beta Kinect SDK you can download from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27876

But before uninstall the Kinect SDK 1.5.